# Calculating 100% height in flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive

I found some topics about calculating height in flutter, but noone of them answered my question. I am trying to calculate `100% of device height` in flutter. I assume, I have to subtract from `MediaQuery.of().size.height` two things. First is `AppBar` height, so I calculated it by creating variable `appBar` and get property `preferredSize.height`. Second is the bar above `appBar` (which contains things like battery status, notifications etc.).

This is the simplest example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var appBar = AppBar(
  title: Text(widget.title),
);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: appBar,
  body: Center(
    child: Builder(
      builder: (ctx) => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height -
                MediaQuery.of(ctx).padding.top -
                appBar.preferredSize.height,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

This is my main Widget so I had to create context with `Builder`. However, it is not still equal to 100% of device height. It is 24px too much. I don't want to subtract 24px because It might be more/less on another device. What is wrong with this example?

Comment: You'll get total height after appBar and statusBar with `height: MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height`, that actually reduce something automatically. Don't substact anything.

Comment: I am not sure about that. I tried it and instead of 24px too much, I have now 80px too much. I think I need to subtract `AppBar` height and `StatsBar` padding but it still is not equal to the remaining device height.

Comment: try to use a `LayoutBuilder` and wrap it with a `SafeArea` Widget, then you can inside the builder function of the `LayoutBuilder` access the height which will be what you want!
For reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610742/proper-way-to-get-widget-height-in-safearea)

Comment: Try with wrapping `Container` widget as parent of `Builder`

Comment: Wrapping `Builder` with `Container` didn't helped. Changing `Builder` to `LyoutBuilder` and using `SafeArea` didn't help either (80px too much) even if i subtract `appBar.preferredSize.height` and `MediaQuery.of(ctx).padding.top` (24px too much).

Comment: Since i started using flutter `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` has always delivered the full height of the device. The thing that is wrong is the question. If you want the container to fill the height, wrap it in an `Expanded` Widget instead

Comment: Yeah, agree. I've asked wrong question. I mean I wanted to Widget to occupy 100% of remaining space (without NavBar and StatusBar). It worked when I did what you suggested @ValdaXD and it worked. But how can i calculate remaining space programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `Expanded` because one of it children is  `Column` and `ListView` which want's to take as much as avaiable space left. If I don't specify height, I will get an error: "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded". I think I still need to calculate remaining screen space. Any ideas why given example doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe delete the `Center` widget and use Column as the body? . Scaffold will stretch the "root" body to fill the remaining space automatically. Since it's stretching center, and center doesn't  stretch it's child. Then column will have an undefined height.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special to the child of the `Scaffold`. Unless the child widget manages its own sizing, it will fill the entire remainder of the area inside of the `Scaffold` by default. In the case of `Container`, its behavior is to shrink wrap to the size of its child, but if it doesn't have a child, it will fill all available space. So you can just do this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Depending on the child widget, you may need to manually configure a size, but most layout widgets either you won't need to worry about it or it just takes a bit of configuration. With `Column`, for example, if you set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`, then it will also automatically stretch to fill all available space. You can then make use of `Expanded` to size its children based on available space as well.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
    body: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

However, on the seldom occasion you need the exact numbers of the space available, you don't usually want to use `MediaQuery` as that will get you the size of the entire screen, not just the available space, and you usually will have to perform additional calculations to boil it down to the size you are actually looking for (which usually leads to incorrect results, as you have discovered).

Instead, you can use a `LayoutBuilder`. A word of caution here, you don't want to abuse `LayoutBuilder` as it adds an additional layout step to its children, so having a lot of them in your code can easily slow down your app.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final width = constraints.biggest.width;
        final height = constraints.biggest.height;
        return Center(
          child: Text('Width: $width, Height: $height'),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]